# PHP FTP Get the status when copying large files

Tags: php, ftp

OK have this simple code, i am pulling over very large GB+++ ZIP files and instead of not knowing what is going on I would like to be able to out put like 1% done, 2% done, or something to show signs of life

```
    echo "getting file $zip_name...";
    if(ftp_get($ftp_conn, $zip_name, $zip_name, FTP_BINARY)){
        ftp_delete($ftp_conn, $zip_name);
        echo "...got file and removed $zip_name from server...";            
    }
```

Comment: Notice the "duplicate" questions does not have a complete working answer only some code that dopesn't work and a suggestion

Comment: I've posted a full code in the duplicate question.

Comment: Btw, it looks like you are not accepting answers you are getting to your questions on SO. Please revisit your past questions and accept and/or upvote good answers.